# How to fetch value of app.kubernetes.io/name in Go?

Tags: go, kubernetes

What is the correct way to fetch the value of `app.kubernetes.io/name` label value of a microservice using Go?

Comment: What type of k8s object is that? pod? deployment?

Comment: Need to fetch for all kinds of objects. Pods, Deployments, Daemonsets etc. One example would be helpful.

Comment: Downward API:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/